# Inbox says I have an answer but no answer appears

Tags: support, deleted-answers, global-inbox

For [this question in SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/387390/how-do-we-copy-a-custom-table-style-from-word-to-outlook/387533#387533) an answer is showing in my inbox but there's no answer shown in the question.

[image]

Does this mean the answer is going to appear in due course (and the popup inbox is just getting ahead of us) or has the poster already deleted it (shame?!?) in which case will the Inbox eventually remove it also?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The post owner deleted the "answer". Would have been deleted as not an answer in that state anyway.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I don't have 10k reputation on SuperUser to check for certain, but psychic debugging would point to the answerer (or somebody else) has deleted the answer.

Comment: I wish I could do psychic debugging...

Comment: Engineers call it a SWAG.